Sent Pepe Coin from Kraken to Wisex
I transferred pepe from Kraken to my Wisex wallet and it’s not showing, first time so not sure what’s happened but showing as completed? Any help to see what’s happened would be greatly appreciated.
0xe409402613a48fde8bf4a0b409c6db5a0dd5ec45d66e4c5c41e05b93d68cb1dd

That transaction is confirmed on mainnet, checked using a block explorer. Either the wallet doesn't support that token, or you have to configure it. I'd suggest to try with a different wallet.
